# Run appengine endpoints on non-default module

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

I was trying to run app engine endpoints on a non-default module, but the generated JAR's dont point to the correct module.

My module name is :

```
<module>business-module</module>
```

I generate the JAR's using :

```
business-module:appengineEndpointsInstallClientLibs
```

When I open the resulting jars I see :

```
public static final String DEFAULT_ROOT_URL = "https://project-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/";
public static final String DEFAULT_SERVICE_PATH = "blahApi/v1/";
public static final String DEFAULT_BASE_URL = "https://project-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/blahApi/v1/";
```

But technically it should have been :

```
public static final String DEFAULT_ROOT_URL = "https://1-dot-business-module-dot-project-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/";
public static final String DEFAULT_SERVICE_PATH = "blahApi/v1/";
public static final String DEFAULT_BASE_URL = "https://1-dot-business-module-dot-project-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/blahApi/v1/";
```

I can run the api fine from the api explorer by opening :

> https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://1-dot-business-module-dot-project-id.appspot.com/_ah/api#p

EDIT

There is a related issue on the [bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&groupby=&sort=&id=9916)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, got it working.
Basically I set the rootURL to point to the correct module while building the Api :

```
final BlahApi businessApi = CloudEndPointsUtils.updateBuilder(new BlahApi.Builder(transport, factory, credential)
.setRootUrl("https://1-dot-business-module-dot-project-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/")).build();
```